# PHP query string manipulation for MySQL-Searchquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, replace

Following problem.

I have this function:

```
function getProductIds($mysqli_object, $propID, $countpropID) {
    $temp_query = "SELECT prodID FROM table WHERE propID IN (?) GROUP BY prodID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT propID)>=$countpropID";
    $query = str_replace("?", implode(",", $propID), $temp_query);
    $result = $mysqli_object->query($query);
    ...
}
```

$propID is an array of all propertyIDs selected.
$countpropID is an integer of how many properties have been choosen.

I'm trying, given at least two elements in $propID, to insert them all at the exact location where the "?" is at in $temp_query

The idea was that I implode $propID, separated by a "," and use it as direct input to str_replace(). But this doesn't work. It says $reuslt is undefiened.

So now the question to you guys is:

How can I insert the content of $propID in the exact spot where "?" is located at, separated by "," ?

Answer (score -1):

Don't reinvent the wheel.

Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: If you click the link in my answer, you will find numerous examples